# MVC5 & jQuery: Programatically add several items to dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Im quite new on using MVC5. I have a dropdownlist, after the selection it triggers the controller and controller returns a list of items. I want to add those items to an another dropdownlist.

.cshtml

```
<select class="comboBox" id="urunGrubu">
<option></option>
</select>
```

script

```
    function getCinsItem() {
    var value = document.getElementById("urunCinsi").value;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Kuyumcu/UrunEkle1",
        data: { k: value },
        success: function (data) {
            var select = document.getElementById("urunGrubu");
            for (index in data) {
                select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(data[index], index);
            }
        }       
    });
}
```

The value which returns from controller:

```
'["14 AYAR","18 AYAR","21 AYAR","22 AYAR","24 AYAR","8 AYAR","HURDA","SADE"]'
```

This adds all the letters in the list as an option to the dropdownlist. How can I catch words instead of letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that `<option>` inside the select and also in the loop don't need to specify which option you want to use like this `select.options[select.options.length]`

When you get the data, just append `new Option` (that is an element) to the select element in the DOM.

**EDIT**:
Since we talked in the comments and you said that when the data came from controller it says that the type is `string`, it means that you don't have a real array, you have just a string representation of this array. 
So, what you need? a Parse, probably, a `JSON.parse(data)` before iterating it, to avoid the iteration on every character.

Below is an example with the parsing:.

```js
var data = '["14 AYAR","18 AYAR","21 AYAR","22 AYAR","24 AYAR","8 AYAR","HURDA","SADE"]'
//Above is a string that came from controller
console.log("Type before parse:", typeof data)

var select = document.getElementById("urunGrubu");

data = JSON.parse(data)
console.log("Type after parse:", typeof data) //parsed as an object/array

for (index in data) {
    select.append(new Option(data[index], index));
}
```

```html
<select class="comboBox" id="urunGrubu">
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now i realized, when i put the data inside the script as you did it works perfect, but when i run it with the data coming from the controller, its taking every letter as an option. I checked the returned data again, and its completely same.

Comment: when data come from controller, in the `success` function, you logged it and it is exactly an array with 8 elements? It doesn't seem to make sense, because when adding options to a select with jQuery, it doesn't count from where the data came, it just adds...

Comment: the data is a list. i put an alert to my success function and this is exactly what i get: ["14 AYAR","18 AYAR","21 AYAR","22 AYAR","24 AYAR","8 AYAR","HURDA","SADE"]

Comment: please, put a console.log, it's more realiable, then see in the console this value. Also, what is the first option in the select, after you add the option values? It is an `[`, or a `"` or an `1` ?

Comment: console log result: ["14 AYAR","18 AYAR","21 AYAR","22 AYAR","24 AYAR","8 AYAR","HURDA","SADE"]        first option is [

Comment: ok, one last question, please do: `console.log(typeof data)` it shows object or string?

Comment: console.log(typeof data) it says string

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question properly.

I feel like you want to add each item of your array as a new option of the dropdown.

If it is the case, then the code your provided works great.
I had no problem reproducing the behavior on this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb10cg85/32/) (the commented line works aswell)

---

**Edit after your comments :**
You stated that a string is returned to your ajax request, which is totaly viable, as shown in Calvin Nunes's answer.

But if you dont want to parse the string as an array or jsonObject from client-side, you can update your controller method from this :

```
public IActionResult UrunEkle1(TypeOfParameter k)
{
   //Retrieve the data you have to return
   return data;
}
```

To this :

```
public JsonResult UrunEkle1(TypeOfParameter k)
{
   //Retrieve the data you have to return
   return Json(data);
}
```

And from now on, you don't need to parse the result to use it as a json or array, which can but very useful when retrieving a complex set of data, such as a list of custom class. You could use this list this way :

```
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(data[index].label, data[index].id, data[index].isDefaultSelected, data[index].isSelected);
```

Hope it completes accepted answer !

```js
window.populateDropdown = function() {
  var select = document.getElementById("urunGrubu");
  for (var index in data) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(data[index], index);
    //select.options.add(new Option(data[index], index));
  }
}
var data = ["14 AYAR", "18 AYAR", "21 AYAR", "22 AYAR", "24 AYAR", "8 AYAR", "HURDA", "SADE"]
```

```html
<select class="comboBox" id="urunGrubu">
  <option>Default Option</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="populateDropdown()">
Trigger
</button>
```

Of course the first  tag is totally optional and is only usefull for instructions such as "Select an option"

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now i realized, when i put the data inside the script as you did it works perfect, but when i run it with the data coming from the controller, its taking every letter as an option. I checked the returned data again, and its completely same.

Comment: Is your ajax response a json or is it just a string ? In the case of a string maybe you will have to format it yourself before appending data.
Do not be afraid of using console.log, alerts, inline debugger or even VS Breakpoint to examinate the returned value !

Comment: yea looks like it returns string

Comment: I edited my answer to ensure you dont return a string from server-side.